# Querying tables that consist of google sheets data, google big query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have been trying to query from a temporary table (table definitions) that consists of google sheets data but I keep getting error in  code.gs. Below is my code:

```
function test(){

var projectId = 'projectId';
var datasetId = 'datasetId';
var tableId = 'tableId';
var sheet_url = 'the_url_of_google_sheet';

var tableName = 'sheet_tab';
var tableProps = {
    externalDataConfiguration:{
    sourceUris: [sheet_url],
    googleSheetOptions:{
      skipLeadingRows: 1
    },
    sourceFormat: 'GOOGLE_SHEETS',
    autoDetect: true 
   }
}
var tableDef = {};
tableDef[tableName] = tableProps;
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' +tableName+';';

var jobConfig = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationQuery();
jobConfig.destinationTable = {projectId : projectId, datasetId : datasetId, 
tableId: tableId};
jobConfig.query = sql;
jobConfig.writeDisposition = 'WRITE_APPEND';
jobConfig.tableDefinitions = tableDef;

var queryR = BigQuery.Jobs.query(jobConfig, projectId)
}
```

The error message is 'TableName' could not be resolved, dataset name is missing.

Comment: In general, you need to supply the exact error message being received, and indicate which line results in the error. For this case, I believe your issue is that  you are attempting to concatenate a sql string and an object (`tabledef`), rather than just the BigQuery table identifier.

Comment: actually there aren't any examples that i could find, i have just wrote that based on the understanding i got from table definitions page of google api. regarding the sql generated, how can i find out where is the problem as i cant run it in big query - a temp table will be created once i run it.

Comment: also just further updated the code - that is the whole function that i am trying to get to work first before i write the rest. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#temporary-tables - mentions about temporary tables and how table definitions can be defined.

Comment: Edit your post to include the MCVE of your current error.

Comment: Updated the code and the current error. It seems like it is not recognising the tableName as external data source (temp table) and asking for dataset. I am checking further what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your error when calling BigQuery originates in the invalid SQL you send. Your SQL is invalid because you concatenate a string (`"SELECT * FROM"`) with an `Object`. You need to append the table identifier, not the table definition, to the SQL. (You also are missing a space between the "FROM" keyword and the added content.)

From the [page you link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#temporary-tables), it gives an example (in Python) of constructing a table definition for a temporary table:

```py
# Configure the external data source and query job
external_config = bigquery.ExternalConfig('GOOGLE_SHEETS')
sheet_url = "some url"
external_config.source_uris = [sheet_url]
external_config.schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('name', 'STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('post_abbr', 'STRING')
]
external_config.options.skip_leading_rows = 1  # optionally skip header row
table_id = 'us_states'

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.table_definitions = {table_id: external_config}  # <-- variable assignment in constructor

# Example query to find states starting with 'W'
sql = 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE name like "W%"'.format(table_id)

query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)  # API request
```

The takeaway is that the table name to use in your SQL is the property in which you have stored the table definition. In your code, this would be `"tab"`:

```
var tabledef = {
  tab: { // <--- the name of your temporary table is "tab"
    sourceUris: [sheet_url],
    googleSheetOptions:{
      skipLeadingRows: 1
    },
    sourceFormat: 'GOOGLE_SHEETS',
    autoDetect: true 
  }
}
```

Note that the Python code is able to use variable key assignment in the literal object constructor for its `dict`, while similar ("shorthand") is [not valid in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728567/create-the-objectids-map-with-variable-keys-for-a-duplicateobject-request/51732281#51732281) (but can be done in newer JavaScript versions).

A more explicit way of identifying the table for a given query, to both you and anyone who needs to understand your code:

```
const tableName = /** .... */;
const tableProps = {
  ...
};
const tableDef = {};
tableDef[tableName] = tableProps;
var query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ";";
...
```

Comment: I updated this aswell:   var jobConfig = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationQuery();
  jobConfig.tableDefinitions = tableDef;
  jobConfig.query = sql;
    
  var queryR = BigQuery.Jobs.query(jobConfig, projectId);

This gives a new error which is:
Table name "tableName" cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing.