# Key Value Pair initialization not working with variable?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to understanding why the behavior of these two lines of code are  behaving differently I am also trying to create the behavior in example one using variables such as in example two, please see example below:

```
  var kv = {
    'abc': 'moon',
  };
  Browser.msgBox(kv['abc']);
```

returns moon as expected.

```
  var f = 'abc';
  var r = 'moon';
  var kv2 = {
    f: r,
  };
  Browser.msgBox(kv2[f]);
```

returns undefined.

Comment: On the second example, use `var kv2 = {[f]: r};` read about [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). Otherwise the name of your key will be `f` and you will have to do `Browser.msgBox(kv2["f"]);`

Comment: @Shidersz Google apps script currently uses an older version of Ecmascript so computed property names are not (yet) supported.

Comment: @DimuDesigns Oh, I see, in that case he will need to do `var kv2 = {}; kv2[f] = r;` if he still wants to use the `key` and `value` from variables.

Comment: @Shidersz Exactly!

Comment: See my answer here for related explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732281/9337071

Answer (score 3):

On the second example you are creating `kv2` as an `object` with an unique `property` named `f`.

```js
var f = 'abc';
var r = 'moon';
var kv2 = {
  f: r,
};

console.log(kv2);
console.log(kv2.f);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

The new ECMAScript (`ES6`) includes a feature named [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) that will be adequate for what you are trying to do, i.e, use a property name stored in some variable. Example:

```js
var f = 'abc';
var r = 'moon';
var kv2 = {
  [f]: r, // Using computed property name!
};

console.log(kv2);
console.log(kv2[f]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, and from `wikipedia`, you can see this feature isn't available for you:

> Apps Script is a scripting language for light-weight application development in the G Suite platform. It is based on `JavaScript 1.6` with some portions of `1.7` and `1.8` and provides subset of **ECMAScript 5** API.

So, the best you can do, if you still want to use a property name stored in a variable, is this:

```js
var f = 'abc';
var r = 'moon';
var kv2 = {};
kv2[f] = r;

console.log(kv2);
console.log(kv2[f]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: excellent explanation. If he wants to use a variable for the property name, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use object notation:

```
  Browser.msgBox(kv2.f);
```

Answer (score 0):

These two methods work for me:

You can actually see in this situation kvr = {f:r} that the editor is showing that the key is not receiving the substitution.

```
function sampletest() {
  var f='abc';
  var r='moon';
  var kv2={abc:r};
  Browser.msgBox(kv2[f]);
}

function sampletest1() {
  var f='abc';
  var r='moon';
  var kv2={};
  kv2[f]=r;
  Browser.msgBox(kv2[f]);
}
```